# Remove non meaningful characters in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, string, regex-group

I am trying to remove all

```
\xf0\x9f\x93\xa2, \xf0\x9f\x95\x91\n\, \xe2\x80\xa6,\xe2\x80\x99t
```

type characters from the below strings in Python pandas column. Although the text starts with b' , it's a string

```
    Text
  _____________________________________________________
"b'Hello! \xf0\x9f\x93\xa2 End Climate Silence is looking for volunteers! \n\n1-2 hours per week. \xf0\x9f\x95\x91\n\nExperience doing digital research\xe2\x80\xa6

"b'I doubt if climate emergency 8s real, I think people will look ba\xe2\x80\xa6 '

"b'No, thankfully it doesn\xe2\x80\x99t. Can\xe2\x80\x99t see how cheap to overtourism in the alan alps can h\xe2\x80\xa6"

"b'Climate Change Poses a WidelllThreat to National Security "

"b""This doesn't feel like targeted propaganda at all. I mean states\xe2\x80\xa6"

"b'berates climate change activist who confronted her in airport\xc2\xa0
```

The above content is in pandas dataframe as a column..

I am trying

```
string.encode('ascii', errors= 'ignore')
```

and regex but without luck. It will be helpful if I can get some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Your string looks like byte string but not so `encode/decode` doesn't work. Try something like this:

```
>>> df['text'].str.replace(r'\\x[0-9a-f]{2}', '', regex=True)

0    b'Hello!  End Climate Silence is looking for v...
1    b'I doubt if climate emergency 8s real, I thin...
2    b'No, thankfully it doesnt. Cant see how cheap...
3    b'Climate Change Poses a WidelllThreat to Nati...
4    b""This doesn't feel like targeted propaganda ...
5    b'berates climate change activist who confront...
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Note you have to clean your unbalanced single/double quotes and remove the first 'b' character.

Answer (score 0):

You could go through your strings and keep only ascii characters:

```
my_str = "b'Hello! \xf0\x9f\x93\xa2 End Climate Silence is looking for volunteers! \n\n1-2 hours per week. \xf0\x9f\x95\x91\n\nExperience doing digital research\xe2\x80\xa6"
new_str = "".join(c for c in my_str if c.isascii())
print(new_str)
```

Note that `.encode('ascii', errors= 'ignore')` doesn't change the string it's applied to but returns the encoded string. This should work:

```
new_str = my_str.encode('ascii',errors='ignore')
print(new_str)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it's not removing the unwanted charecters

Comment: How so? the characters are gone when I print `new_str`... Have you tried to run my code?

Comment: I am using python 3.*   From my end when I'm trying it's not removing the unwanted charecters. Is there repository where I can upload the data so that you can check. Thanks.

Comment: Check this out: [jdoodle.com/ia/iYq](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/iYq)